# Logging to a multi-column database with NLog?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, nlog

In my ASP.NET Web API project, I'd like to log some call-specific details to the database.

In particular, I'd like to write the api version requested, and the actual log.

I have tried this:

```
<commandText>
  INSERT INTO ApiLogs(EventDateTime, EventLevel, EventMessage, ControllerName) VALUES (@EventDateTime, @EventLevel, @EventMessage, @ControllerName)
</commandText>

<parameter name="@EventDateTime" layout="${date:s}" />
<parameter name="@EventLevel" layout="${level}" />
<parameter name="@EventMessage" layout="${message}" />
<parameter name="@ControllerName" layout="${event-context:item=asdf}" />
```

with this:

```
public void CustomDebug(Logger logger, String message)
{
    LogEventInfo theEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Debug, logger.Name, message);
    theEvent.Properties["asdf"] = "hardCoded";

    logger.Log(theEvent); 
}
```

, but when I do so, my ApiLogs database looks like this:

```
ApiLogGuid                              EventDateTime           EventLevel  EventMessage                                                                                                                        ControllerName
8EC7AB18-FDB8-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 13:51:34.000 Info        DocumentType: W2    
8FC7AB18-FDB8-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 13:51:35.000 Debug       TESTING CUSTOM DEBUG    
D664ED50-FDB8-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 13:53:08.000 Info        DocumentType: W2    
D764ED50-FDB8-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 13:53:09.000 Debug       TESTING CUSTOM DEBUG    
CEA78D9A-FDB8-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 13:55:11.000 Info        DocumentType: W2    
CFA78D9A-FDB8-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 13:55:14.000 Debug       Log Event: Logger='API.Controllers.v1.DocumentsController' Level=Debug Message='TESTING CUSTOM DEBUG' SequenceID=2  
D0CB0C9E-00B9-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 14:16:45.000 Debug       Log Event: Logger='API.Controllers.v1.DocumentsController' Level=Debug Message='testing' SequenceID=1   
D1CB0C9E-00B9-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 14:16:46.000 Info        DocumentType: W2    
D2CB0C9E-00B9-E311-8628-00188B35784D    2014-03-31 14:16:47.000 Debug       Log Event: Logger='API.Controllers.v1.DocumentsController' Level=Debug Message='TESTING CUSTOM DEBUG' SequenceID=4
```

Hard to show here, but there is NOTHING in that final column.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed.

`<parameter name="@ControllerName" layout="${event-context:asdf}" />`

instead of

`<parameter name="@ControllerName" layout="${event-context:item=asdf}" />`

was all I needed. Finally!